# cherche le ode API de la langue Tamazigh dans Google Translate

Tags: android

Google Translate test la langue en version beta: le Tamazigh (berbere afrique du Nord)
Je souhaite tester cette langue dans nos web-applications.
je cherche le code ISO (API) du Tamazigh  (pour le français le code est fr)

Comment: please post your question in english

Answer (score 0):

Tamazight language has not yet been integrated into google translate api, but soon it will be there. As the news tells which you can refer over here -> https://www.moroccoworldnews.com/2019/03/268676/google-translate-morocco-amazigh-tamazight-language/
And also you can check for the availability of google translate languages over here -> https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/languages
Thank you.